# Unity shows pixelated noise in Scene

Tags: unity

I have open Unity today with a weird bug happening. I can see pixelated noise (I don't know what else to call it), and restarting Unity or my Mac does not work. What can I do? It doesn't affect the game, this just shows in the Scene.

EDIT:

It indeed seems that it has something to do with the camera GameObject; when I remove the Camera the problem goes away. Re-creating the camera does not solve the problem.

It seems the problem goes away when setting the Camera setting "HDR" to "Off", but that still doesn't explain why it happens in the first place.

[image: unity pixelated scene]

Comment: Does it disappear if you delete one of the 4 game objects you have in your scene?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Philipp; indeed the problem seems to be attached to the Camera. However, when deleting and adding a new camera, the same glitch appears.

Comment: Aha... setting "HDR settings" to "Off" instead of "Use Graphic Settings" makes the problem go away! Thanks! Although that doesn't explain why this happens in the first place all of a sudden; any ideas?

Comment: This seems like it would be a graphics card problem with one of the rendering settings on the camera. This may be good to bring up as a support question with Unity staff

Comment: Glad you figured out how to solve it, even if you still don't know why it happens. Please write an answer to document this problem with a solution for future users (edit the answer in the future if you happen to find out why it happens)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the GameObject "Camera" was the culprit; more specifically setting the option "HDR" to "Off". I'm going to contact the Unity support to see if they can help get to core issue, but for now at least I was able to get rid of the pixel glitch.

Comment: Do you have an update on the situation?